# Does the Cloudant python library cache the database between executions of a serverless function?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, couchdb, cloudant, serverless

I have a serverless function calling a Cloudant database via the [python-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant) library, with the connection to the client being made outside the function handler so that it is cached, like so:

```
httpAdapter = HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=5, pool_maxsize=100)
client = Cloudant(cloudantUsername, cloudantPassword, url=cloudantURL, adapter=httpAdapter, connect=True)

def update(event, context):
    db = client['db_name']
    document_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    document = db[document_id]
    document['foo'] = 'bar'
    document.save()
    return json.dumps(document)

def get(event, context):
    db = client['db_name']
    document_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    document = db[document_id]
    return json.dumps(document)
```

When I do this, I get a very low latency (<100ms) on repeat executions of any kind (create, update, get), because the "connection" is reused, which is the intention. ("connection" in inverted commas since cloudant / couchdb does not have a concept of keeping an open pipe).

I have noticed some strange behaviour, however - if I call `/update` and increment the document `_rev` to `2-XXXX` then call `/get` the function returns document with `_rev` `2-XXXX`. If I call `/update` again, `_rev` is correctly incremented to `3-XXXX`, but when I call `/get` again, I get document revision `2-XXXX` (i.e. not the updated version). When this is happening, the update function is executing in ~90ms, while the get is executing in ~10ms (too fast to actually be calling the database).

I can eliminate this behaviour by moving the setup of the Cloudant client inside the function handler like so:

```
httpAdapter = HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=5, pool_maxsize=100)

def update(event, context):
    client = Cloudant(cloudantUsername, cloudantPassword, url=cloudantURL, adapter=httpAdapter, connect=True)
    db = client['db_name']
    document_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    document = db[document_id]
    document['foo'] = 'bar'
    document.save()
    return json.dumps(document)

def get(event, context):
    client = Cloudant(cloudantUsername, cloudantPassword, url=cloudantURL, adapter=httpAdapter, connect=True)
    db = client['db_name']
    document_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    document = db[document_id]
    return json.dumps(document)
```

When I do this, `/get` always returns the correct revision of the document. This behaviour is unexpected since I believed putting the client setup outside the handler would only cache the client between executions, but calls to the database would still be made each time. It looks like they are being made when `/update` is called, but not when `/get` is called.

Is putting the client declaration outside the handler somehow caching the database? If so, is there any way to prevent it from doing so?

Edit: I have found that the function can be forced to call the database with the client declared outside the handler, by explicitly calling `document.fetch()`, like so:

```
def get(event, context):
    db = client['db_name']
    document_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    document = db[document_id]
    document.fetch()
    return json.dumps(document)
```

Comment: CouchDB, and thus Cloudant, doesn't use persistent connections. It's an HTTP-based protocol, so there is no connection to cache. I'm not sure what you think is being cached, but it's not a server connection.

Comment: I expect the core of your question comes down to [eventual consistency](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/consistency.html), though.

Comment: @flimzy I originally thought this was a replication / eventual consistency issue (i.e. read and write looking at different replicas), but since the `document.fetch()` seems to resolve the issue, I don't believe it is. The client simply isn't calling the database, but I wasn't expecting this behaviour - I believed the database needed to be called every time, but there is some caching happening.

Comment: Have you ever witnessed similar behaviour but for other functions e.g. `get_query_result`? Results appear to be being cached in some way. Problematic as the `QueryResult` object doesn't have a `.fetch()`.